# Join 2 subqueries

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I would appreciate any assistance w/this. I'm trying to perform a join on 2 subqueries, but it keeps saying the 'IntEncTracking.EncounterList.ClaimId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause, but I've tried qualifying it with an el and q2, to no avail. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

> Declare @SweepId as int = 10160, @RunType as varchar = 'Initial'
>
> ```
> Select * from (Select distinct ClaimId
>      , LineNum
>      , 0 as EncounterLineNum
>      , EncounterType
>      , InternalICN
>      , PreviousDpwICN
>      , 0 as ClaimFrequencyCd
>      , EncounterPeriod
>      , 2 as StatusCd
>      , BypassReason
>      , null as EncounterFileNm
>      ,@SweepId as SweepId
>   from IntEncTracking.EncounterList
>  where bypassflag = 1) as q1
>
>  join
>
>  ( Select  ClaimId
>      , 0 as LineNum
>      , 0 as EncounterLineNum
>      , EncounterType
>      , InternalICN
>      , PreviousDpwICN
>      , max(ClaimFreqCd) as ClaimFreqCd
>      , max(EncounterPeriod) as EncounterPeriod
>      , case when exists (select 'x' 
>                            from IntEncTracking.EncounterList el1 
>                           where el1.claimid = claimid
>                             and BypassFlag = 0) then 1 
>             else 2 
>          end stscd
>      , case when @RunType = 'Initial' then 100 else 300 end as [StatusReasonCd]
>      , null as EncounterFileNm
>      , @SweepId as SweepId
>   from IntEncTracking.EncounterList el
>  where BypassFlag = 0) as q2
>
>   on q1.ClaimId = q2.ClaimId and
>      q1.LineNum = q2.LineNum and
>      q1.EncounterLineNum = q2.EncounterLineNum and
>      q1.EncounterType = q2.EncounterType and
>      q1.InternalICN = q2.InternalICN  
>      group by q1.ClaimId, q1.EncounterType, q1.InternalICN, q1.PreviousDpwICN      
>      order by q2.ClaimId, q2.LineNum, q2.EncounterLineNum, q2.EncounterType, q2.InternalICN
> ```

Comment: You don't have a `from` clause.  `join` is not like `union` and `union all`.  It can only appear in a `from` clause.

Comment: Okay, so I've tried editing to the above, but still a no go...any suggestions, please?

Comment: Thanks Gordon and everyone. It turns out I was taking the wrong approach with this query...until next time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

this is just a syntex..

```
Declare @SweepId as int = 10160, @RunType as varchar = 'Initial' 

select *

from   (Select distinct ClaimId
     , LineNum
     , EncounterLineNum
     , 0
     , EncounterType
     , InternalICN
     , PreviousDpwICN
     , 0
     , EncounterPeriod
     , 2
     , BypassReason
     , null
     ,@SweepId
  from IntEncTracking.EncounterList
 where bypassflag = 1) as q1

join    
     (Select  ClaimId
     , 0 as LineNum
     , 0 as EncounterLineNum
     , EncounterType
     , InternalICN
     , PreviousDpwICN
     , max(ClaimFreqCd) as ClaimFreqCd
     , max(EncounterPeriod) as EncounterPeriod
     , case when exists (select 'x' 
                           from IntEncTracking.EncounterList el1 
                          where el1.claimid = claimid
                            and BypassFlag = 0) then 1 
            else 2 
         end stscd
     , case when @RunType = 'Initial' then 100 else 300 end as [StatusReasonCd]
     , null as EncounterFileNm
     , @SweepId
  from IntEncTracking.EncounterList el
 where BypassFlag = 0) as q2


 on q1.ClaimId = q2.ClaimId and
 on q1.LineNum = q2.LineNum and
 on q1.EncounterLineNum = q2.EncounterLineNum and
 on q1.EncounterType = q2.EncounterType and
 on q1.InternalICN = q2.InternalICN 
 group by ClaimId, encountertype, internalicn, PreviousDpwICN
  order by ClaimId, LineNum, EncounterLineNum,EncounterType,InternalICN
```

Comment: Thanks AJP, but I was getting more errors, so I had to make some more changes, but still having issues:

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '8'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 41
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: first remove space from this..   , 0 as col 8 and change it to , 0 as col8 then try again.

Comment: Okay did that, but now it's giving me: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Column 'IntEncTracking.EncounterList.ClaimId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 43
No column name was specified for column 12 of 'q2'.

Comment: looks like you changed your query.. re-post the new query.

Comment: change your select to q1.ClaimId, q1.EncounterType, q1.InternalICN, q1.PreviousDpwICN. this will fix your problem.. than add whatyou need one by by in select. you should look at how group by works. google it.

Comment: Thanks AJP. It turns out I was taking the wrong approach with this query.

Answer (score 0):

I always do this sort of stuff like this

```
    ;with EncounterValues as(
    SELECT
    CommonValueOrId,
    ect..
    FROM
    IntEntTracking.EncountrList
    )

    , EncounterFileNums as(
    SELECT
    CommonValueOrId,
    ect..
    FROM
    IntEncTracking.EncounterList
    )

    SELECT
    ev.AnyField,
    efn.AnyField
    FROM
    EncounterValues ev
    LEFT JOIN EncounterFileNums efn
    ON ev.CommonValueOrId = evn.CommonValueOrId
```

Not sure what the implications of doing it this way is but might be worth giving it a go if you're struggling.

Comment: Thanks Scott Allen. It turns out I was taking the wrong approach with this query...so until next time then. :-)