# Multiple SQL queries and FOREACH - Can be JOINED to one?

Tags: php, sql, join, foreach, expressionengine

I am trying to pull a list of Events, also seeing which members have paid for the Events. I then want to see if they are on the committee, to see if they have admin permissions.

I have successfully done this, using three SQL queries, then using three foreach loops to build the Array.

I am SURE this can be done with one SQL query and one foreach loop, however I have not yet mastered the JOIN technique.

I am using Expression Engine, Codeigniter Active Record, I will display to you the SQL output and also what my current EE functions look like.

THANKS FOR THE HELP! :D

### **SQL to select ALL events which are active**

```
SELECT `id` as event_ID, `name` as event_name, `description` as event_description
FROM (`events`)
WHERE `events_category_id` =  '1'
AND `active` =  1
ORDER BY `name` asc
```

**EE CODE to achieve this:**

```
$query = $this->theDb->select('id as event_ID, name as event_name, description as event_description')
            ->order_by("name", "asc")
            ->get_where('events', array('event_category_id'=>$event_type,'active'=>1));
```

**

### SQL to find what EVENT IDs the user has paid for

**

```
SELECT DISTINCT `products`.`event_ID` as joinedID
FROM (`transactions_items`)
JOIN `transactions` ON `transactions`.`id` = `transactions_items`.`id`
JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `transactions_items`.`product_id`
JOIN `events` ON `events`.`id` = `products`.`event_ID`
WHERE `transactions`.`member_id` =  27500
AND `events`.`active` =  1
AND `event_category_id` =  '1'
ORDER BY `events`.`name` asc
```

**EE CODE to achieve this**

```
$query = $this->theDb->select('products.event_ID as joinedID')
        ->distinct()
        ->order_by("events.name", "asc")
        ->join('transactions', 'transactions.id = transactions_items.id')
        ->join('products', 'products.id = transactions_items.product_id')
        ->join('events', 'events.id = products.event_ID')
        ->get_where('transactions_items', array('transactions.member_id' => $memberID, 'events.active' => 1,'activity_category_id'=>$activity_type));
```

### **SQL to find ADMIN rights**

```
SELECT `events`.`id` as event_ID, `admins`.`admin_role_id` as role_id, `admins_roles`.`name` as role_description
FROM (`admins`)
JOIN `admins_roles` ON `admins`.`admin_role_id` = `admins_roles`.`id`
JOIN `events` ON `events`.`id` = `admins`.`event_ID`
WHERE `admins`.`member_id` =  27500
AND `events`.`active` =  1
```

**EE CODE to achieve this**

```
$query = $this->theDb->select('events.id as event_ID, admins.admin_role_id as role_id, admins_roles.name as role_description')
        ->join('admins_roles', 'admins.admin_role_id = admins_roles.id')    
        ->join('events', 'events.id = admins.event_ID') 
        ->get_where('admins', array('admins.member_id' => $memberID, 'events.active' => 1));
```

### FOR EACH LOOPS

```
// Create list of Events setting defaults
foreach($events_list as $row)
{
    $combinedEvents[$row->event_ID] = array(
        'eventID' => $row->event_ID,
        'eventName' => $row->event_name,
        'eventDescription' => $row->event_description,
        'isJoined' => 0,
        'roleID' => 0,
        'roleDescription' => "",
    );
}
// Add Committee roles
foreach($admin_list as $row)
{
    $combinedEvents[$row->event_ID]['roleID'] = $row->role_id;
    $combinedEvents[$row->event_ID]['roleDescription'] = $row->role_description;
}   
// Add Transactions
foreach($transaction_list as $row)
{
    $combinedEvents[$row->joinedID]['isJoined'] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the FOREACH part because I've never touched PHP - but you should be able to solve the multiple SQL queires using the **;with** clause. I have created an example in response to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17685772/1700309) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17701010/1700309). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, however I am more looking at the best way to 'JOIN' this query, so that it returns ONLY the information I need, within one query. The other problem is that this has to be done with EE's Active Record syntax